# How to access a web site from a native Windows application?

Tags: windows, webclient

I hope this is a simple question.

Using .NET, I could simply access a Web site using:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUserName", "Password123");
string fileContent = wc.DownloadString("https://example.com/example.txt");
```

Unfortunately, I am working on a native 64-bit DLL file which is used as plug-in in another program.

So I have no chance to use .NET but I can only use native 64-bit Windows DLLs.

Are there any native Windows APIs that do the same as the code above?

I have searched the Internet, but I found nothing.

Comment: The functions in "wininet.dll" seem to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer myself:

The functions of "wininet.dll" are the solution:

The function [InternetOpen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetopena) more or less corresponds to `new WebClient()`.

Downloading data is a bit more complicated; there is no unified API for different protocols (HTTP, FTP, ...), but each protocol type uses different functions.

To download (`GET`) or send (`POST`) data via HTTP or HTTPS, the APIs [InternetCrackUrl()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcrackurla), [InternetConnect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetconnecta), [HttpSendRequest()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpsendrequesta) and [InternetReadFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetreadfile) are used.

(Note: On the Microsoft web site documentation, the function declarations are shown as `void InternetOpen(...)` although the documentation says that the functions return a value of the type `HINTERNET`. `HINTERNET` is correct, `void` is wrong.)